# Global store vusjs

Tags: vue.js

Im trying to create global store with example from internet, and i did it, but store not refreshing values.

Thats my store `globalStore.js`

```
var store = {
  debug: true,
  state: {
    message: "Привет!",
  },
};

export default {
  store,
  // we can add objects to the Vue prototype in the install() hook:
  install(Vue, options) {
    Vue.prototype.$myStore = store;
  },
};
```

Thats how i import it in app.js

```
import globalStore from "./globalStore";
Vue.use(globalStore);
```

and how i use it in app.js

```
 data() {
    return {
      ts: this.$myStore.state.message,
    };
  },
```

but when im trying to change value from another component

```
methods: {
    vs() {
      this.$myStore.state.message = 25;
      console.log(this.$myStore.state.message);
    },
  },
```

in console value changing, but in page i have old value. If thats code not good, maybe someone knows how to create dynamic globalstore in vue?

Comment: You should read up about [mutations](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html#object-style-commit)

Comment: I used Vuex to wrap the store in my Vue application but even then I am pretty sure you can _not_ simply assign values to the store and expect things to change, you might need at least to use a method to change the store to intercept that call.